# How to maintain continuous Session in Dot Net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state

I am facing an issue in my application that whenever user search for any data and then keep the application idle for like 15-20 mins, and then try to perform any operation on the application, then the application crashes. I am using simple DevEx Grid to show data and ahve details rows and Popup control for that grid.

I think the issue is with the sessions as my application was unable to maintain the session for that duration and due to which application crashes.

Moreover, i have not used any session variables into my application for data.

I cannot find the real cause for this error.

Can somebody help me for the same.

Comment: increase session time out or if you wish to keep user preference in application life cycle, store data in application variable instead. Handle the exception, and log out user if data not available for operation

Comment: Even increasing session time is of no use, as my application is crashing after that. i have set session time out to 30 Mins but if application is idle for 30 mins or more then application crash, i have to stop that crash and not to increase session time out.

Comment: Use cookies instead of session to keep details live on user browser session... and handle the cookies to populate initial data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write client side javascript to make ajax calls to the server.
This will keep your session alive.

It allows you to have a short timeout at the server, and still a long time out for idle users.

Be sure to have a timeout though, in case your user is away for a hour, the page should log him out.

Comment: Thanks i want this kind of functionality but can you tell how can i make blank ajax calls.

Comment: There are many methods to do this. Simplest would be to create an aspx page and call it using XMLHttpRequest https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_xmlhttprequest. Look at javascript frameworks like jquery to be cross browser complaint.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the session timeout in IIS to a really high number or minutes (like 1440 for an entire day). This setting is in the "Session State" area.

Another option would be to use Opera as your browser, and load the page once. After that, use Opera's "reload page every..." option to automatically reload the page every minute. This would extend the session forever.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't store anything useful in session, you should make a way it could reload without crashing. For this you need to anylyse when the crash happens and find a way to prevent the crash. either by initializing with a sane default or catch the exception and start fresh.